# How Can I use gensim package in Azure ML?

Tags: machine-learning, text-analysis, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using text analysis with Azure ML. So in my python script I want to create a bag of word model and then calculate TFIDF of each words. For that I am using gensim model, It's not working on Azure ML. So is there any options for me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste the error and also please check the documentation on installing additional packages as shown here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-extend-your-experiment-with-r/#importing-packages

That being said, you can also try new modules "preprocess text" and "Extract n-gram" with 1-gram for creating bag of words as shown in the experiment here - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Predict-Book-Reviews-1

[image]

Comment: I want to run python scripts on azure ML. And Azure ML has anaconda installed so I can use those libraries with out any problems. But this gensim model is not in the anaconda package but in my local pc I have installed the gensim model to the anaconda and ran the code. But how can I run this on Azure ML ?

Comment: You have to zip genism package and upload to azure ML as zip file (+New->click data->upload zip file). Then follow instructions provided here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-execute-python-scripts/#importing-existing-python-script-modules

Comment: So it's like we are running a script. So we can use that zip version as a input to our python script running on the Azure ML.

Comment: Exactly. You can add the missing libraries as a zip file and refer them within your python code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

generally if you have a model trained externally, you can pickle it and bring it into Azure ML for scoring by uploading it as a ZIP package and feed it to the ZIP input port of an Execute Python Script module.